# Attempted import error: 'react-pdf' does not contain a default export (imported as 'PDFViewer')

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf, pdftables

After installing react-pdf and then doing: import PDFViewer from "react-pdf"; The below error is shown:
Attempted import error: 'react-pdf' does not contain a default export (imported as 'PDFViewer').
Why is it shown? And how to get rid of this error? I can't even figure out what the actual problem is.

Basically I tried enclosing the PDFViewer in curly braces ({PDFViewer}), but then it says: "Module not found: PDFViewer is not exported from react-pdf".
Also I tried doing "react-pdf/renderer" instead of "react-pdf", still it said "Module not found react-pdf/renderer".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This error was taken from console, and the error is shown in node-modules. So, i don't understand how can i provide code for people to understand it better. From what i know, maximum people here, and i mean like 97-98% people (which i'm also a part of), don't know the 'abc' of node-modules